# saving checkbox values in django form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm trying to make a boards function, where you select the clothes you want (in checkboxes), but i'm not being able to save the checked items into my django model because the form is invalid

my html (with checkboxes for each item):

```
                <form method='POST' action="{% url 'create-boards' %}">
                    <div class="select-display">
                        <h3 id="select-text">Select</h3>
                            <div class="select-container">
                                {% for item in clothes %}
                                    <div class="column stacked featured">
                                        <input class="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="selected_clothes">
                                        <label for="mycheckbox">
                                            <img class="gallery column__img"  src="{{ item.image.url }}">
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                 {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </form>
```

models.py

```
class Clothes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='wardrobe/')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clothes'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.color} {self.title} from {self.brand}'
    
class Boards(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    selected_clothes = models.ManyToManyField('Clothes', null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import User, Clothes, Boards

class BoardsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Clothes.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        required=True)
    
    class Meta: 
        model = Boards
        fields = ('title','description','selected_clothes')
```

views.py

```
def create_board(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BoardsForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = request.POST['title']
            description = request.POST['description']
            selected_clothes = form.save(commit=True) 

            create_boards = Boards(title=title, description=description, selected_clothes=selected_clothes)
            create_boards.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(boards))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('the form is invalid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code looks good but you haven't specified the value of the checkbox which you are actually need to submit through your form and also add the {% csrf_token %} to your form.

the final code looks like

```
                                    <input class="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="selected_clothes" value="{{item.image.id}}">
```

or

```
        <input class="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="selected_clothes" value="{{item.image.url}}">
```

using the id of the image is better feel free to modify according to your requirements and the updates views.py as

selected_clothes = request.POST.getlist('selected_clothes')

and iterate through the list of all elected items and save them manually its better to avoid unintended errors

Hope this works for you